# Simple java - looping over a txt file of numbers, counting the numbers between a range

Tags: java, loops, file-io, range

I'm using Netbeans, and I'm trying to write a code that loops over a .txt file full of numbers (numbers.txt), and output the amount of numbers that are within a range, e.g 10-100, along the lines of "There are __ numbers within the range of 10-100"

I then want the code to be able to add up all of the numbers in this range to get a total, e.g 13+33+70+90 = 206, and print this out along the lines of "The total of numbers in the range = 206"

I would give you the code I've done so far but it doesn't work at all as I can't figure out how to loop over the numbers.txt file to begin with.

Comment: Having the code that you *have* written is helpful because it gives an indication of where the problem you are having is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the numbers one by one and calculate total and counter.

```
int total=0,counter=0,num; //initialize total and counter to 0

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt")); //scanner to scan integers from file
while(scan.hasNextInt())
{
    if((num=scan.nextInt())>=10 && num <=100) //if num is in range of 10-100
    {
        total+=num; //adding num in each iteration
        counter++;  //increment counter
    }
}

System.out.println(counter+" numbers found in the range 10-100 and their sum is "+total);
```